# WordPress Ajax request is showing 400 error message

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to validate a form using jQuery Ajax in WordPress. Here is my workflow:

**Action:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_reg_action', [ $this, 'reg_action' ] );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_reg_action', [ $this, 'reg_action' ] );
```

**Function:**

```
public function reg_action() {

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['reg_nonce_field'], 'reg_action' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>s';

    exit;

}
```

**Nonce field:**

```
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'reg_action', 'reg_nonce_field' ); ?>
```

**Localize Script**

```
 wp_localize_script( 'sdl-js', 'sdl', array(
    'ajax_url' =>  admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
) );
```

**jQuery Ajax Call**

```
;(function($) {
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $(".registration").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var form_data = $("#registration_data").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url : sdl.ajax_url,
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'html',
                data : {                   
                    action: 'reg_action',
                    form_data : form_data,                    
                },
                success : function( result ) {
                    console.log( result );
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

BUT every time it's showing me **400 Bad Request** :( :( :(

Can you tell me why? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `console.log(sdl.ajax_url)` returns? Have you checked if it is a valid url or not?

Comment: it's returning `http://wp.test/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering your php function?

Test your JS with

```
$.post(
    sdl.ajax_url, {
        "action": "reg_action",
        "form_data": form_data,
        "dataType": "html",
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Comment: no luck. same 400 error message: Here is the debug: https://prnt.sc/rfxa56

Comment: Ah, found the error. The PHP function was in a Class but I didn't initialize it :( :(